# What's the difference between these functions created by `Function`?

Tags: javascript, function, new-operator, function-constructor

1.`var f = new Function("a", "b", "return a+b")`

2.`var f2 = Function("a", "b", "return a+b")`

`f` and `f2` both are a anonymous function. `f(1,2)` and `f2(1,2)` both returns `3`. So is there any actual internal difference between the two?
Does `Function` internally return a function object? Difference from using the `Function` as constructor`new Function(...)`?

Answer (score 7):

From the [ECMAScript 5.1 specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3):

> When Function is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it
>   creates and initialises a new Function object. Thus the function call
>   Function(…) is equivalent to the object creation expression new
>   Function(…) with the same arguments.

Comment: Cool! just checked with the ecma 6 as well, same spec. :)